# Can I use OS X Time Machine to set up my development environment?

Tags: macos, time-machine

I have my personal MacBook Air set up the way I want for development.

I also have a work MacBook Pro. Can I use Time Machine to mirror my personal setup onto the work MacBook?

Comment: are you asking if you can use it to keep them synced, or simply to duplicate one to the other?

Comment: @mcgrailm just duplicate one time

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is backup both machines.

The best way to clone your machine is to put the MacBook pro in to Target mode

1. Connect the two computers with a FireWire or Thunderbolt cable.
2. Start up the computer to be used as a disk in target disk mode by holding T on startup.

then on the Air open disk utilities select the Air's HD on the left and choose restore tab. VERY IMPORTANT make sure the source is the Air's drive and the MacBook (in target mode) is the destination. Then restore.

This will clone the Air to MBP.

when you are done use time machine to restore your personal data from backed up MBP to the newly cloned machine.

That is how I would handle this.